# Can't connect to google MySql cloud instance from java cloud endpoint

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-sql

I have a MySQL instance on google cloud and I am trying to access it from java cloud endpoint as given below:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
String url = "jdbc:mysql://cloud_sql_ip_address:3306?user=root&password=dbpassword";
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
```

However I am getting this error:

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I don't understand how come localhost feature in the logs as I am trying to connect to IP address of my MySQL instance. Please let me know what I am doing wrong over here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove password part from the URL as given below:

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://cloud_sql_ip_address:3306?user=root";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead

```
String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver"

String url = "jdbc:google:mysql://<your-project-id>:<your-instance-name>/<your-database-name>?user=root"
```